# Cannot set selected elements for the list module on Joomla Fabrik extension

Tags: joomla, html-lists, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I am using free version of Fabrik extension on Joomla. Both my Joomla and Fabrik are the latest version

I have already done with the Fabrik structure part such as create the form, elements, group, list, and set the form order, validations, appearance, and make them all works. Any registered user can submit the data using the form and it'll be stored into a table on the database

On the front-end, the idea is the user can view two different list view modules through his/her profile, a private list and a public list

- Module A lists only entries submitted by the user. The list show the whole entry's data
- Module B lists all of the entries submitted by everyone. The list show only selected data from selected field from each entry

This where the problem came from. When I gonna create a module for the list view (Fabrik List Module)

> Module Manager > New > Fabrik List Module > Advanced

After I set the title and the list, when I clicked on the 'Select' button for attribute 'Elements', it just response me like I just clicked on 'Cancel', and redirect me to the modules list table instead. If it is just an unfixed bug, I can do nothing about it, but I guess it'll be a lot easier if I can just set something directly using database admin

Comment: sorry for my bad english. i'll accept any grammar fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some little hacking, i've succesfully figured it out. Go to [pre]_menu.params (for menu item) or [pre]_modules.contents (for module), and you'll see some json like this

```
{"calculations":"0","listlayout":"bootstrap","resetfilters":"0","list_elements":"null", ....}
```

Just replace list_elements value from "null" to this

```
"{\"show_in_list\":[...]}"
```

[...] contains the list of elements id (inside table [pre]_fabrik_elements) we want to select them on module view, for example [1,2,3,4,5]

**updated :**

It's very unpractical solution to just modify the joomla data directly on database. Actually, especially in similar case to mine (sure it is a bug), you can select the elements for a list view (as asked) by simply creating a new separated list apart from the auto generated list which is generated by default on form creation.

That new list will automatically generate new set of elements with new ID based on database table structure, and plus they will not shared their setting with the default list. Alter the default list should definitely be avoid as it will totally change the behavior of the form

On the new list, you can simply un-"show in list" any elements you don't want to show, and create either menu item or module linked to the new list. This is also the best way if you want to alter the list displaying such as change the list header field title, change the list description, or join others elements to the list